# Does it matter which edge is FROM and TO in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I'm wondering if in the following example, [taken from the wiki](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Create-Edge), it matters which edge goes in the `from` section and which goes in the `to` section

```
create edge from #10:3 to #11:4
```

Or is performance the same when traversing either way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performances are the same for both in and out, so what matters if the meaning of direction for your connection.

The direction is only related to how you traverse them: out() or in().